# writing details for house sale advertisement

Tags: word-usage, confusable

I was posting an house sale advertisement and wanted to say that all the rooms of the house dont have any problems with light and fresh air passes through the rooms. How can i write about that in the advertisement .

Comment: "Well-lit" and "well-ventilated"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Maciej Stachowski says, well-ventilated is a good option. Real estate advertisements often use such phrases to describe the wellness of the houses to sell, buy or rent.

*Out of many ways*, you may simply say...

> The house has good natural lighting and ventilation.

The [whole document published by NZ Government (downloadable PDF)](http://www.minedu.govt.nz/~/media/MinEdu/Files/EducationSectors/PrimarySecondary/PropertyToolbox/ModernLearning/VentilationIndoorAirQualityGuide.pdf) on natural lighting and ventilation is here. It's in the interest of public to learn about it.

Read the document and you might include some more jargon to make your advertisement effective! :) All the best.